# How to use @XmlIDREF and @XmlID

Tags: java, xml, annotations, jaxb

I don't quite understand how `@XmlIDREF` and `@XmlID` work together. By using `XmlIDREF` I only create a reference to the actual element. However what is the use case for `XmlID`.

I want to create a reference to the class `Publication`. Is it enough to annotate the publication List with `@XmlIDREF`?

```
public class Author {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<Publication> publications = new LinkedList<>();

    public Author() {
        super();
    }
    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @XmlIDREF
    public List<Publication> getPublications() {
        return publications;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to create a reference to the class `Publication`.
>     Is it enough to annotate the publication List with `@XmlIDREF`?

No, that's only one half of what you need.

- You already have this:
  With `@XmlIDREF` you mark the *referencing* side of the relation
  (pointing from `Author` to `Publication`).

  ```
  public class Author {

      ...

      @XmlIDREF
      @XmlElement(name = "publication")
      public List<Publication> getPublications() {
          return publications;
      }

      ...

  }
  ```
- You also need to mark the *referenced* side (the `Publication` itself)
  by annotating one of its properties with `@XmlID`, for example like this:

  ```
  public class Publication {

      ...

      @XmlID
      @XmlElement
      public String getId() {
          return id;
      }

      ...
  }
  ```

Then you are able to process XML content like this example:

```
<root>
    <publication>
       <id>p-101</id>
       <title>Death on the Nile</title>
    </publication> 
    <publication>
       <id>p-102</id>
       <title>The murder of Roger Ackroyd</title>
    </publication> 
    ...
    <author>
       <id>a-42</id>
       <name>Agatha Christie</name>
       <publication>p-101</publication>
       <publication>p-102</publication>
    </author>
    ...
</root>
```

You see, the XML references (like `<publication>p-101</publication>`)
are mapped to Java object references (in `List<Publication> publications`).