# IllegalAnnotationExceptions: XmlIDREF property is referencing a type “java.lang.String” that doesn't have an XmlID property

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a class that has just the `id ref` that points to `id` in other classes as shown below. I am getting the above `IllegalAnnotationExceptions`. Where am I missing or having wrong addition of annotations? Here are my files below:

Note that I haven't shown the xml root element class here as these elements are 1-2 levels nested inside the root. Let me know if anyone wants to see the root as well.

`PartyReference.java`

```
package xyz;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlIDREF;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType
public class PartyReference {

    private String refId;

    public String getRefId() {
        return refId;
    }

    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlAttribute(name = "refId")
    public void setRefId(final String refId) {
        this.refId = refId;
    }
}
```

`Person.java`

```
package xyz;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlID;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import java.util.List;

@XmlType(propOrder = {})
public class Person {

    private String id;
    
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

`SenderIssuer.java`

```
package xyz;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(propOrder = { "sameAsSuspPerson", "sameAsOtherPerson", "fullName" })
public class SenderIssuer {

    private PartyReference sameAsSuspPerson;
    private PartyReference sameAsOtherPerson;
    private String fullName;

    public PartyReference getSameAsSuspPerson() {
        return sameAsSuspPerson;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "sameAsSuspPerson")
    public void setSameAsSuspPerson(final PartyReference sameAsSuspPerson) {
        this.sameAsSuspPerson = sameAsSuspPerson;
    }

    public PartyReference getSameAsOtherPerson() {
        return sameAsOtherPerson;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "sameAsOtherPerson")
    public void setSameAsOtherPerson(final PartyReference sameAsOtherPerson) {
        this.sameAsOtherPerson = sameAsOtherPerson;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "fullName")
    public void setFullName(final String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
}
```

I checked a couple of posts including this one but it does not answer my question: [How to use @XmlIDREF and @XmlID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56375499/how-to-use-xmlidref-and-xmlid)

`DIFFERENCE FROM THE ABOVE QUESTION BCOZ`
My structure of xml looks like where references are mapped to attribute ids and the nested element refId attribute refers to another element's id attribute.

```
<report>
    <person id="id1">
        ...
    </person>
    <person id="id2">
        ...
    </person>
    <senderIssuer id="si1">
        <sameAsSuspPerson refId="id1" /> <-- This refers to person with id1 -->
    </senderIssuer> 
</report>
```

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice.  If you disagree that this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/56375499/18157, then you should your original question and indicate why you think it's not a duplicate and how the proposed solution fails to solve your problem.  Merely saying _"it does not answer my question"_ is insufficient, you need to tell us how your problem is different.

Comment: @JimGarrison Sure. Since SO told me to either Edit or Delete the question and on editing, it still showed my question as closed so I deleted it and created a new one, thinking that was expectation. Let me add how it's different here.