# SAXException2: Object is found in an IDREF property but this object doesnt have an ID

Tags: java, soap, xml-parsing, sax

I am working on a SpringBoot application with Java8 that is a proxy used to put a REST interface on a SOAP service.  As a result, I need to convert a number of POJO's to generated SOAP Objects to call the SOAP service.

This all works perfectly, however I have one generated class that is  giving  an error, because it does not have a defined member variable (i.e. it is of type `Object`).

**ProximityToLocation.java**

```
public class ProximityToLocation extends Locator implements Serializable {
    @XmlElement(
        required = true
    )
    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlSchemaType(
        name = "IDREF"
    )
    protected Object to;
```

As you can see with the generated `ProximityToLocation` class above, it has a member variable named `to` of type `Object`.  I know from looking at other SOAP calls to the service, that the `to` object needs to be of generated type `GPSLocator`.

**GPSLocator.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "GPSLocator",
    propOrder = {"latitude", "longitude"}
)
public class GPSLocator extends Locator implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected double latitude;
    protected double longitude;
```

As a result, I set the `to` object to a `GPSLocator`, but when it tries to call the SOAP service, it gets the following error:

> SAXException2: Object
> "com.xxx.transit._2008a.location.GPSLocator@6b3cda96" is found in an
> IDREF property but this object doesnt have an ID

I am setting the `Object` to a `GPSLocator` because that's what I see being set as when I intercept the direct SOAP calls that are working.

**Solution**

To  me it seems like the `to` object needs an ID, but I don't understand how to set it because the classes are not  mine (i.e. I can't change them).

I guess if the `GPSLocator` class had the following it would work:

```
@XmlID
@XmlElement
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

**Problem**

The classes referred to above a classes that are generated by a third part who hosts the SOAP service, so I cannot modify these classes.

**Question**

How do I add the `id` to the generated class that is not mine?

**More Info**

Thanks to the comments below, it was suggested that I subclass the `GPSLocator` class and add the `id`.  So I tried the folloiwng:

```
public class GPSLocator extends com.xxx.transit._2008a.location.GPSLocator {

    protected String id = Double.toString(Math.random()*1000);

    @XmlID
    @XmlElement
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

However, even if I use this new class, I still get the same error above.

```
[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: Object "com.xxx.restosgi.dto.transit.location.GPSLocator@6ea818f2" is found in an IDREF property but this object doesnt have an ID.]
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use @XmlIDREF and @XmlID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56375499/how-to-use-xmlidref-and-xmlid)

Comment: As you assumed correctly, your `GPSLocator` needs a field (either a `@XmlElement` or `@XmlAttribute`) annotated with `@XmlID`.

Comment: My problem is the `GPSLocator` class is generated by a third party who own the SOAP service, so I cannot change it, ie. to add the ID field.  So I was wondering if there was a why to do this?  Should I perhaps use reflection to add a new member variable to the class at runtime?

Comment: you cannot add fields at Runtime. You could subclass GPSLocator though and add that field to the subclass.